# how to convert nested dictionary into table using python for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I have a nested dictionary which look like this:

```
m = {'match':{'football':{'cricket':'batball','player':'joe','match':36}}}
```

and I want to convert this dictionary into table using for loop without using pandas Dataframe.

This my code:

```
m = {'match':{'football':{'cricket':'batball','player':'joe','match':36}}}
for i in m:
for j in m[i]:
    print(j + " : " + str(m[i][j]))
```

output:

```html
match     cricket  player match
football  batball  joe    36
```

Comment: Can you provide the desired output ?

Comment: What is `student`?

Answer (score 0):

This creates the desired output without using pandas! Definitely not an extendible solution! But serves the purpose

```
m = {'match':{'football':{'cricket':'batball','player':'joe','match':36}}}
first_row = []
second_row = []
for key, value in m.items():
    first_row.append(key)
    second_row.append(list(value.keys())[0])
    for key_1, value_1 in value.items():
        for key_2, value_2 in value_1.items():
           first_row.append(key_2)
           second_row.append(str(value_2))

print('\t\t'.join(first_row))
print('\t\t'.join(second_row))
```

**Output:**

```
match       cricket     player      match
football        batball     joe     36
```